# Execute 'x2 Serperate Maven Projects' at the 'Same Time' from 'Jenkins'?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Execute 'x2 Serperate Maven Projects' at the 'Same Time' from 'Jenkins'?

1. Lets say I have **projectA**
2. and **projectB**
3. Both projects execute tests which last .45seconds each.
4. Each project A and B are assigned their own jenkins build.
5. Is it possible to execute both builds at the same time therefore both tests are executing simulatansiesly from two seperate builds (Same jenkins instance) and x2 seperate Maven projects.
   [image]

Comment: it seems that it is possible from the screenshots. What is the problem?

Comment: @mosaad just need the opinions of others based upon whether the is the correct procdure to conduct or should it be tacked via other means.

Comment: Please remove the selenium, selenium-webdriver and webdriver tags from this question. They are not related to the question you have asked..